# Next / preview row of a database query

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image]

I have this page in front of me.
What I want to do is when I press the button next or previews to change the index there via AjAX.

According to the image, when I press the Next image-button the text must change to 'andreas', if i press next again change to 'NEWW' then to 'apoel' and then to 'Name Surname' again.

I have this code when pressing the ACTORS link:

```
/* FOR THE ACTORS TAB */
litActors.Text = "";
actorsCmd = "SELECT actor_name,a.id_actor FROM actor a JOIN project_actor pa on a.ID_ACTOR = pa.ID_ACTOR WHERE ID_PROJECT = " + Request.QueryString["id"];
SqlCommand cmdActor = new SqlCommand(actorsCmd, con);
SqlDataReader reader;
try
{
     reader = cmdActor.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
          litActors.Text += "<li><a onclick=\"javascript:getSummary(" + reader.GetInt32(1).ToString() + ",'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('" + reader.GetString(0) + "') \">" + reader.GetString(0) + "</a></li>";

     }

}
catch (Exception err)
{
     con.Close();
     return;
}
```

the html representation of the code above is this(ignore those style.display. They are for the interface):

```
<ul class="slideShow actors">
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(62,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('Name Surname') ">Name Surname</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(1,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('andreas') ">andreas</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(63,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('NEWW') ">NEWW</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(53,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('apoel') ">apoel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now my javascript functions are like this:

```
function getSummary(id,type) {
    if (id == "") {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    if (type == 'a') {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "desciptionActorHelper.aspx?id=" + id, true);
    } else if ...

    xmlhttp.send();
}

function displayActor(nameActor) {
        var btnActor = document.getElementById('displayMe'); btnActor.style.display = 'inline';
        btnActor.innerHTML = "<a>ACTOR:</a> " + nameActor;
}
```

and my next/prev buttons:

```
litDescField.Text = "<span id='left_right'>" +
                          "<a><img src='../images/left-arrow.png' /></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" +
                          "<a><img src='../images/right-arrow.png' /></a>" +
                    "</span>";
```

Does anyone has an idea of a **good and easy way** to do it?

Because the my thoughts are very complicated and I am not even sure if they would work.

I was thinking of making a table with the actors ID's(I must run a query to take both the number of actors and their ID too) and onClick of next or prev changing a cursor which says where you are now in the table.

Comment: How do you populate the `'Name Surname', 'andreas', 'NEWW', 'apoel'` list? Manual structuring? DB Query? Also, what is the DB DataType of `ID_PROJECT`

Comment: onclick event I call getSummary() which does an AJAX call of another .aspx page called desciptionActorHelper.aspx which writes the description of  an actor(actor type, actor's role in project etc).

Comment: Let me rephrase. You have an list of "ACTORS", the light yellow box in the upper-left of your picture. How does that list get populated? Assuming it's a DB query, how do you determine the order of the list? Also, what is the DB DataType of ID_PROJECT?

Comment: The order of the list is based on the query I have(actorsCmd). The order is not so important. The DataType of ID_PROJECT is INT32.

Comment: Ok, but 'Name Surname', 'andreas', 'NEWW', and 'apoel' are all seperate actors, correct? Do they have the same ID_PROJECT? How does the query differentiate between them?

Comment: YES separate actors with the same ID_PROJECT!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you consider good or easy, but here's one way to do it:

Change your handler to:

```
SqlCommand cmdActor = null;
SqlDataAdapter da = null;
DataSet ds = null;
DataRow row = null;
int rowIndex = 0;
int rowNext = 0;
int rowPrev = 0;
int rowMax = 0;
bool isFirstRow = false;
bool isLastRow = false;
HtmlGenericControl li = null;
HtmlGenericControl a = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;

litActors.Text = "";
actorsCmd = "SELECT actor_name, a.id_actor FROM actor a JOIN project_actor pa on a.ID_ACTOR = pa.ID_ACTOR WHERE ID_PROJECT = @ID_PROJECT";
cmdActor = new SqlCommand(actorsCmd, con);
//Parameterizing ID_PROJECT to protect against SQL injection
cmdActor.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_PROJECT", Request.QueryString("id"));

try {
    //Using a SqlDataAdapter instead of a SqlDataReader because forward-only access is 
    //not conducive for trying to peek ahead or look-behind
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdActor);
    da.Fill(ds);
    //check returned tables
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
        //Zero-out the row counter and set index of maxRow
        rowIndex = 0;
        rowMax = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1;
        foreach ( row in ds.Tables(0).Rows) {
            //Test to see if the row counter has incremented to the last row
            isFirstRow = rowIndex == 0;
            //Test to see if the row counter has incremented to the last row
            isLastRow = rowIndex == rowMax;
            //Set prev/next rows
            rowPrev = (isFirstRow ? rowMax : rowIndex - 1);
            rowNext = (isLastRow ? 0 : rowIndex + 1);
            //Make new HTML controls
            li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            //Make a StringBuilder to assemble the "onclick" in a more readable fashion
            //subbing in "row("actor_id")" and row("actor_name") for an example of column names
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("javascript:getSummary(");
            sb.Append(row("actor_id").ToString());
            sb.Append(", 'a');");
            sb.Append("document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';");
            sb.Append("document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';");
            sb.Append("displayActor('");
            sb.Append(row("actor_name").ToString());
            //add in the prev/next actor ids to pass to javascript:displayActor();
            sb.Append("', ");
            sb.Append(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowPrev)("actor_id").ToString());
            sb.Append(", ");
            sb.Append(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowNext)("actor_id").ToString());
            sb.Append(");");
            //Add initial "onclick" for the litActors list
            a.Attributes.Add("onclick", sb.ToString);
            a.InnerText = row("actor_name");
            //Add new anchor to litActors
            li.Controls.Add(a);
            litActors.Controls.Add(li);
            //increment row counter
            rowIndex += 1;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception err) {
    con.Close();
    return;
}
```

Which renders the new Actor list as:

```
<ul class="slideShow actors">
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(62,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('Name Surname', 53, 1);">Name Surname</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(1,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('andreas', 62, 63);">andreas</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(63,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('NEWW', 1, 53);">NEWW</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="javascript:getSummary(53,'a');document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'inline-block';displayActor('apoel', 63, 62);">apoel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your JavaScript, two changes are needed:

```
function getSummary(id, type, callback) {
    if (id == "") {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //CHANGE 1: Execute callback, if supplied
            if (callback) {
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } else (
                //Default action
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    if (type == 'a') {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "desciptionActorHelper.aspx?id=" + id, true);
    } //else if ...
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function displayActor(nameActor, prev, next) {
    var btnActor = document.getElementById('displayMe'),
        span = document.getElementById('left_right');
    btnActor.style.display = 'inline';
    btnActor.innerHTML = "<a>ACTOR:</a> " + nameActor;
    //CHANGE 2: Set prev/next via AJAX
    getSummary(prev, 'a', function (data) {
        //do something with the previous actor
        span.children[0].innerText = data;
    });
    getSummary(next, 'a', function (data) {
        //do something with the next actor
        span.children[span.children.length - 1].innerText = data;
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

My answer already sends the actor_id (for both previous and next actor) to the displayActor function.

Notice in this section (of the code-behind) that I'm using `DataTable.Rows` to get both previous and next actor_ids:

```
//add in the prev/next actor ids to pass to javascript:displayActor();
sb.Append("', ");
//RENDER the PREVIOUS actor_id as a parameter to the "onclick"
sb.Append(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowPrev)("actor_id").ToString());
sb.Append(", ");
//AND THEN render the NEXT actor_id as a parameter to the "onclick"
sb.Append(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowNext)("actor_id").ToString());
sb.Append(");");
```

which renders the `displayActor` call in the "onclick" event as:

```
displayActor('Name Surname', 53, 1);
```

which is why the JavaScript function definition is now:

```
function displayActor(nameActor, prev, next)
```

and the last two commands in `displayActor` are to your AJAX `getSummary` function.

```
getSummary(prev, 'a', function (data) {
    //do something with the previous actor
    span.children[0].innerText = data;
});
```

could also be written as:

```
var callback = function (data) {
    //do something with the previous actor
    span.children[0].innerText = data;
};
getSummary(prev, 'a', callback);
```

If the `xmlhttp.responseText` in your AJAX function returns the current actor, modify `desciptionActorHelper.aspx` to return the previous and next actors as well and simply render them from the response.

Comment: nice!! I like your idea! I will check it out! :)

Comment: I didn't understand the idea with the callback (function(data)).
Callback is a function send as a parameter? 
I will try your solution tomorrow at night!

Comment: Functions in JavaScript can be passed as parameters to another function. Here's one of my favorite resources on the subject: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript. Note in the updated `displayActor()` function that I am passing an anonymous function as the callback parameter for the `getSummary` function.

Comment: Your idea about the next and previews id of an actor is good. But the problem here is that my next/prev buttons are hyperlinks and when they are pressed another actor is displayed. So I thought of having a session instead of type DataTable in which I will store the actor_id,actor_name, next, prev. But the fact now is that I don't know how to set the next/prev hyperlinks having the IDactor JavaScript(I thought of sending the idActor as a parameter to displayActor() function).

Comment: Yeah, I understood that part! But the thing I want to tell you is that whenever(consecutively) I press previews or next it goes to the prev/next actor. If  I am at Name Surname actor and press 2 times next Ajax should give me the description of NEWW actor. That's why I need a Session!

Comment: Ok, I did it with a Session table! thx a lot for your algorithm finding next and previews! :)